Rigify Chain failure, can't generate rig
I have created armature from scratch many times because of this error, but there is a problem every time. I have connected all the bones one by one and I still get this error.

Also, after giving the error message, it creates a copy of the default Armature and I can't use generate rig on it instead of the original armature.

I connected many bones that were giving errors and they no longer give errors. But now the bone named spine.009 is constantly giving errors and I don't know how to proceed anymore.

Don't connect bones by Ctrl + P -> Connected.
If Rigify asks to connect bones, it asks you to match the head and tail of the bones, which can be done by point snapping.
A meta-rig is an assembly of bone chains. A bone chain is identified by the Connected attribute. Bone chains can be further connected together by parenting them without using the Connected attribute (i.e. using the Keep Offset option while parenting). If you change parent type to Connected, you simply broke the structure of meta-rig by connecting two bone chains into a single one.
Each first bone of a bone chain has a custom attribute on it which is a Rigify custom property that identifies the sub-rig type. At rig generation time Rigify will determine which controls and deform bones will be created processing the meta-rig from the first bone to the last of each chain.
Spline.009 is marked in rig as splines.super_head, that mean that it is start of bone chain. And connecting it to spline.008 makes bigger bone chain and loosing bone chain that's started from Spline.009, which brakes structure of sub-rig.

To fix the issue, reconnect bone using Alt + P -> Disconnect bone
See also:
How Rigify Works

I removed the connect I added to all the bones and I still get the same error, the connection points of the bones are on top of each other, but it still doesn't fix it.

Sure, it can be more bones, that connected wrong way. You need to fix them all, or try from start, but this time try not to disconnect bones with matched head and tails and check each step by rig regeneration

Yes, thank you, I fixed the chain error. But now it gives a different error like this, " Generation has thrown an exception: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "ORG-nose" not found' ".

Thanks for your help, I fixed the problems in general and the link you shared was really helpful.
